# ndisuio is not forwarding the EAPOL packets to EAPOL(eapol.dll) module in Windows CE 6.0

Tags: driver, windows-ce, msdn, wifi, ndis

I have problem with the WLAN driver, sometimes its not connecting to WPA AP. while debugging(with debugzones enabled) the issue I found that eapol module is not receiving the EAPOL 1st packet and I don't see ndisuio forwarding the packets to eapol.dll.

Can anyone tell me when does the ndisuio ignores the EAPOL packets from Miniport driver ?

Thanks
Akhil